# How to get the values from jQuery and assign it for hidden field and save it into the DB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hiddenfield

How to get the values from jQuery and assign it for hidden field and save it into the DB?

Actually I am developing a project, where there is some jQuery code for a button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnYes").click(function () {
        $("#btnYes").html("Counted");
        $("#<%= hdnYesNoAnswer.ClientID %>").val("Yes");
        $('#txtComment').focus();
    });
});
```

When I clicked the `#btnYes`, it changes to "Clicked". In that page I added one hidden field called `#hdnYesNoAnswer`. So now what I want is to get the value ("Yes") from that jQuery function and assign it to hidden field `#hdnYesNoAnswer` and save that hidden field value to the SQL Server database.

Comment: You can't do it using javascript. You have to implement the logic on backend where you will handle request from javascript and add data to DB.

Comment: "How do I make a website ?" is what I read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maris is right. Ajax is a defacto technic for these actions. Here are some links. I hope they help

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX